# How can i delete and format sd card partitions that have file system in it?

Tags: dd, sd-card

Ok,I have steam with steam os in it sooo in a way on another i install steam os in sd card
(install steam os in the sf did not end well and got file system that i can not delete or work it) and got same partitions as my internal ssd (assuming my os is **linux**), Now i wanna to format and delete partitions but when i unmount it to format it show error tells that can not unmount partition contain **filesystem** (my sd is **1TB sandisk with speed of 100m per S**)
Tried different things,First i tried to format it using command prompt and disk managment in windows and same error
Tried in linux with KDE partition manager and delete em but when i eject and insert it again as i did nothing and got same partitions
lastly tried command dd with this command `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/mmcblk0 bs=8192`  but it **waaaay** tooo slow it have been 36 Hours (1Tb sd card) and iam afraid after all that waiting the command not solve my problem
sorry for takin ur time but iam really confuse and have no money to buy another sd so please help

Comment: Could you please re-edit your question so that reading & understanding it is not just a nightmare for the community.

Answer (score 1):

1. I am unsure why you're zeroing the whole SD card.
2. Anyway, I'd remove the SD card from your computer now to avoid flushing any further data.
3. Re-insert the SD card and run `gdisk` to create a new partition table on it and a new partition.
4. Then, I'd create a new `ext4` file system on the new partition.

All of the above steps are surely well-documented here, so I assume I don't need to elaborate.

Comment: So u saying that  this command will not fix the issue ?

Comment: and please can u teach me the commands u menshin iam new to linux things

Comment: @عمرجوادكاظم If you are very new to Linux, please just install GParted and use it. It can do almost everything the same as commands from the terminal, but it could be more convenient for you. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: I kinda figure out what the issue,there are command in the sd that run in every boot to mount some partition and unmount some and creat orginal partition ,so how can i deactivate it?